# Response with scrapy shows wrong or other data

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am scratching a page, but when I request a link with all the information it shows me that the data does not exist, but I check the json with the firefox inspector and the response has all the information, I have manipulated the headers, but I have not succeeded in getting me show the data.

my code:

settings.py:

```
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0'
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = False
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 1
DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
```

mi_spider.py:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

from json import loads, dump


N_categoria = 0

API_key = 'P1MfFHfQMOtL16Zpg36NcntJYCLFm8FqFfudnavl'


class MetrocScrapingSpider(Spider):
    name = 'metroc_scraping'
    allowed_domains = ['metrocuadrado.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.metrocuadrado.com/']


    def parse(self, response):
        print()
        print('Entra aca 1')
        print()
        
        aptos_links = response.xpath('//*[@class= "box-list"]')[N_categoria].xpath('.//li//a/@href').extract()

        data_links = []

        for url in aptos_links:
            items = {}
            url = url.split('.com')[-1].split('/')

            for ind, info in enumerate(url):
                if info == '':
                    url.pop(ind)

            items['inmu_'] = url[0]
            items['type_'] = url[1]
            items['loc_'] = url[-1]

            data_links.append(items)

        n_cat = 1


        yield Request(url= response.url,
                      callback= self.first_parse,
                      meta= {'data_links': data_links,
                             'n_cat': n_cat,
                             'aptos_links': aptos_links},
                      dont_filter= True)

    def first_parse(self, response):
        data_links = response.meta['data_links']
        n_cat = response.meta['n_cat']
        aptos_links = response.meta['aptos_links']
        n_from = 0                  

        cat_linl = aptos_links[n_cat]
        data_link = data_links[n_cat]

        print(data_link)

        inmu_ = data_link['inmu_']
        type_ = data_link['type_']
        loc_ = data_link['loc_']

        api_link = 'https://www.metrocuadrado.com/rest-search/search?realEstateTypeList='+inmu_+'&realEstateBusinessList='+type_+'&city='+loc_+'&from='  

        yield Request(url= api_link + str(n_from) + '&size=50',
                      callback= self.main_parse,
                      meta= {'data_links': data_links,
                             'n_cat': n_cat,
                             'n_from': n_from,
                             'api_link': api_link},
                      dont_filter= True,
                      headers= {'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                                'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                                'Accept-Language': 'es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3',
                                'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                                'DNT': '1',
                                'Host': 'www.metrocuadrado.com',
                                'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
                                'Referer': cat_linl,
                                'Pragma': 'no-cache',
                                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0',
                                'X-Api-Key': API_key,
                                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})



    def main_parse(self, response):
        print()
        print(response.url)
        print()
        print(response.status)
        print()

        jsonresponse = loads(response.text)
        print(jsonresponse)
```

[below the link and the response status, is the json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l62Wp.png)

as you can see, "totalHits" is 0, "totalEntries" is 0 too and results is empty. But, if you look at the firefox inspector:

[screenshot of the request headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MImyb.png)

a part of the response in firefox inspector (i dont know if is hard to see but "totalHits" is 3135 and "totalEntries" 3135:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUkpi.png)

i don't know why it happens, any help please ?

Comment: I am not sure but could you try to switch your header position in your yield function like:
header:
callback:
etc...

Comment: hello @MuratDemir, i did what you said but it still not working.

Comment: You seem to believe that the Firefox inspector shows the page source code. It does not. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/developer-tools.html#caveats-with-inspecting-the-live-browser-dom